# Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) static initialization exception on getDeclaredField() in svg-android library

Tags: java, android-6.0-marshmallow, static-initialization

I'm having some serious problem with this code, from [svg-android](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android):

```
public class ParserHelper {

private static final Field STRING_CHARS;
static {
    try {
        STRING_CHARS = String.class.getDeclaredField("value"); //<-- exception here
        STRING_CHARS.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private final char[] s;
private final int n;
private char current;
public int pos;

public ParserHelper(String str, int pos) {
    try {
        this.s = (char[]) STRING_CHARS.get(str); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    this.pos = pos;
    n = s.length;
    current = s[pos];
}
```

the `STRING_CHARS = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");`throws the excpetion

> 10-09 10:25:58.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3430): Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field
>   value in class Ljava/lang/String; (declaration of 'java.lang.String'
>   appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

I can't continue the job. Only in Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Any idea?

**SOLVED:**
Now, I did not solved the static initialization issue but I changed the `char[] s` initialization:

```
public class ParserHelper {

//  private static final Field STRING_CHARS;
//  static {
//      try {
//          STRING_CHARS = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
//          STRING_CHARS.setAccessible(true);
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          throw new RuntimeException(e);
//      }
//  }

    private final char[] s;
    private final int n;
    private char current;
    public int pos;

    public ParserHelper(String str, int pos) {
        try {
            s = new char[str.length()];
            str.getChars(0, str.length(), this.s, 0); //<-- here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        this.pos = pos;
        n = s.length;
        current = s[pos];
    }
```

Comment: Dont you need to use a String instance to perform reflection? not an expert on it.

Comment: @Nanoc me neither...

Comment: Then try this instead and tell me "new String("Hello").class.getDeclaredField("value");"

Comment: @Nanoc Can't compile, error on .class "Syntax error on token class..."

Comment: OK silly mistake, use getClass() instead of .class "new String("Hello").getClass().getDeclaredField("value");"

Comment: Accessing private fields via reflection is risky. They are private for a reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the `String`'s private field called `value` which holds the array of chars was renamed to `ASCII` in the Marshmallow. Thus you have a `RuntimeException` in these lines (taken from the `com.larvalabs.svgandroid.ParserHelper` class):

```
    try {
        STRING_CHARS = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        STRING_CHARS.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

The `svgandroid` is [discontinued](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android), so there is little chance that the project's author will fix this issue and push the new jar to maven.You can make your own fork of svgandroid library, merge [this pull-request](https://github.com/meghneelgore/svg-android/commit/c4515da355dca63b3d3b45ab98b68dafcd0d5506), build the jar and use it from now on instead of mavenized version.

Or you can go a little further, and push the fixed version to mvnrepository yourself. :)

Comment: Oh dear... If anyone would make a fix for this library, it would be awesome. I think many people use it, and now all of their apps are crashing on marshmallow.

Comment: Although your answer do fix it, I wonder if it will have any impact on performance. I think it was done that way to be more efficient as the new methods create a copy and through reflection he is accessing it directly.